# New icon design guidelines for Google Play Store

Tags: android, google-play

Starting Nov 9th, 2023 Google TV will require developers to provide a square app icon asset as part of the submitted TV app package in addition to the existing banner asset. Guidelines are available here: [Guidelines](https://developer.android.com/design/ui/tv/guides/system/tv-app-icon-guidelines)

So we have to add `android:icon` in `AndroidManifest.xml` file for TV.

Icon sizes differ between mobile (48x48px, 72x72px, 96x96px, 144x144px, 192x192px) and TV (80x80px, 120x120px, 160x160px, 240x240px, 320x320px).
Also on mobile for legacy devices that don't support adaptive icons, we were able to make them transparent with rounded edges. You cannot create rounded icons on TV according to guidelines.

How can now we combine launcher icons in one application for mobile devices and TV?

Comment: I posted this question on https://issuetracker.google.com/, and they told me to ask this question here.